# Delphi Tstringlist, write file synch

Tags: delphi, file-io, delphi-7, tstringlist

I make a very simple log with tstringlist. I write it to file:

```
pLog.SaveToFile(FileName);
```

Somewhere there is a bug, and my computer is shut-down.
After, I cannot find my log file. Probably the file is saved in asych mode.
There is a way for waiting for the write before to go on with the execution?

Thanks,
Alberto

Comment: If there's a bug, it's most likely in your own code. Is `pLog` assigned? Can you `step through (F7)` and follow the code in `classes.pas`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the *savetofile* call is at the program end, and the program terminates abnormally, then this call probably won't execute. I use a logging mechanism which for every log call opens the log file, writes the log text and time, flushes and then closes the log file. This way, the log text is guaranteed to be written to a file, even if the program terminates abnormally.

Here's the code:

```
procedure TMainForm.Log (const s: string);
var
 f: textfile;

begin
 assignfile (f, logfilename);
 {$I-}  // yes, I know: modern programming style requires a try/except block
 append (f);
 if ioresult <> 0 then rewrite (f);
 {$I+}
 writeln (f, datetostr (now), ' ', timetostr (now), ' ', s);
 flush (f);
 closefile (f);
end;
```

Comment: +1 good call. This gives a highly plausible reason for the occurrence of option 1 from my answer.

Comment: Of course I disapprove of old-style Pascal I/O but that's a different matter!

Comment: This is one case where I think it's better. This will keep working even when the heap is corrupt, whereas, something that requires you to allocate a filestream or use a filestream object from the heap, will cause this logging code itself to fail, when the heap memory is corrupt, which is really annoying.

Comment: @Warren Hardly. Look at all the heap allocations in the function itself, in the call to `writeln`.

Comment: Ah yes.  _NewAnsiString in Delphi 7, for instance, calls System._GetMem. Okay. This code does allocate strings. I would probably write my logging code so it's heap neutral, and that would mean no non-const use of String types whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks, I have already change it to do in this way. I'm waiting for a computer shutdown :-) to see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

`TStringList.SaveToFile` operates synchronously.

The most obvious causes of the problem are:

1. You are not calling `TStringList.SaveToFile`.
2. The file name is invalid (perhaps the path doesn't exist).
3. The file name is in a folder to which your user doesn't have write access (e.g. the program files folder).

Comment: I call savetofile rewriting all the tstringlist. It works, BUT when the computer shutdown abnormally, I found a file of zero length (and I'm sure I write it a couple of time before the shoutdown)

Comment: `TStringList.SaveToFile` operates synchronously. That's not in dispute.